# How can I calculate a large exponential?

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I calculate a number to a very large power? For example, some number to the `1000000000000000000` power

Comment: You calculate it by doing the math, so you must be actually asking something else. What is your issue with calculating it at the moment? Is the issue that you don't know how to store such a large number? Do you not know how to calculate it quickly? Or is it something else that is stopping you?

Comment: Do you need first `n` digits of the answer and an total number of digits? In case you require precise output with all digits it is not possible because of the large number of digits.

Comment: "Not possible" is a bit of an exaggeration. The only real limit is memory to hold the answer, not computational complexity. Given a sufficient amount of money, it would certainly be possible to build a datacenter capable of storing the result of `2^(10^18)`.

Comment: @Jason Watkins, Actually it not only a **memory** which limits the practical solution but also **time**. For example looping over 10^18 digits will take years to output the number because I don't think such data centers exist.

Answer (score 2):

For large numbers beyond the range of `Int64`, .NET has the [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, which "represents an arbitrarily large signed integer". In practice of course, the value that a `BigInteger` can represent is constrained by the available system memory and the CLR's ability to assign all of that memory.

In theory you can do something like this, but in practice you are likely to run out of memory long before you get to `BigInteger.Pow(value, int.MaxValue)`.

```
var value = new BigInteger(x);
var result = BigInteger.Pow(value, 1000000000);
result = BigInteger.Pow(result, 1000000000);
```

Note that since `BigInteger.Pow` takes a regular `int` for the second argument, you will need two (or more) calls to calculate a power larger than can fit in the range of `int`.

That said, it's also important to understand that operations with `BigInteger` will be much slower than math operations with regular numeric types, so you should carefully consider what your overall goal is and whether there is a way to accomplish it without resorting to using `BigInteger`.

Comment: This will not work. The result will be too long to be stored in memory. You will get `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Doesn't that depend on the input? If the input is relatively small then the output would be large, but by no means unmanageable

Comment: You are right, but it will only *work* for `value = 1`.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Are you sure of that? What proof do you have of that?

Comment: @Ivan, Still, I think this is the best answer for the general question being asked. I don't think that `1000000000000000000` was meant as a specific value, but rather as a "large" value. That said, I'm curious whether you've tested it yourself? I only have access to dotnetfiddle at the moment. I'm wondering what the limit is on `2^n` for an unconstrained 64 bit system with say 16gb of memory

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Actually it seems you are right, even with an input of `2` you very quickly get an out of memory exception

Comment: @Kevin Wells, Lets ask math. Let the value be `2`. Then 2^(10^18) will have 10^18 * lg2 decimal digits. It is about `301029995663981195`. You will have longer results for bigger values. Not hard to notice that for `value = 10` resulting length will be exactly 10^18.

Comment: That is definitely a lot of digits, but given a powerful enough computer it is technically possible to store it and do calculations on it. I don't have the faintest idea why you would want to, but it does seem theoretically feasible

Comment: All of the above is true, but I really think it misses the point. The question could just as well have been asked with `1000000` as the example power, which is very easily achievable.

Comment: If there is n't method to this equation, how it was programmed in the calculator windows ????

Comment: There are many methods, just none built in. But in fact, when I try to calculate `2^100000000000000000` in the Windows 7 calculator, I get "Invalid Input" as the answer.

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about exponents? Windows calculator can work with exponents like 5e19 just as well as any calculator, but it cant handle 5^10000000000000000000 at all

Answer (score 0):

There is no data type in C# that can store a value like pow(value,1000000000000000000) (except if value is 1 :P) 
Even BigInteger cannot store such a large number.

Comment: Technically he could write his own type and then given enough time and computational power he could handle it right?

Comment: @KevinWells technically you are correct. But the end result should be stored as series of characters (may be like a string)

Comment: If there is no method to this equation, how it was programmed in the calculator windows ????